# Jquery function to convert java data to json

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json

Is there a jquery function that will convert a java data object to a json?
I am using the HTTPResponse object to serve up my object to my ajax, which returns a String object.

note:
JSON.parse wont work
I cant use any json parsing libraries

Comment: Do you mean Java Data or JavaScript Data?

Comment: Then `JSON.parse` should work. Are you sure your json data is well formed? How are you calling `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Json.parse isnt working.. i receieve an "unexpected error D"

Answer (score 1):

Try using $.getJSON

```
var onSuccess = function(data) {
    //data is now a javascript object
};

$.getJSON("your-url").done(onSuccess);
```